# dynamic button event problem

Tags: iphone

i have some problem..
i have created a dynamic button in a table view. I want to know the method of opening a new view controller when i click the dynamic button in the table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually we have 2 ways to do that.

[Present Modal View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

[Push another view controller using navigation controller](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:)